# Auto Layout - UIButton issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

I started working on a new project with Auto Layout and I'm stuck on a really weird issue. I added an `UIButton` to the `Storyboard` in the form of a `IBOutlet` and set the `NSLayoutConstraints`. The button appears where it should but it did not receive the events action. Then I checked for the frame of the button, and it's outside of the screen.

The frame of the button is outside the screen, but it shows on the screen where it should. Where is the problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to show code for us to help. In your case you should show screenshots of your interface builder / simulator.

Comment: You have to print the frame info from viewDidAppear to be sure its accurate. Make sure you added the UIButton target action properly in IB. Check the UIButton is enabled in the attribute inspector. Check the UIButton does not have any transparent views in front of it which could block the events.